# Create account via API in EOSIO

Tags: php, eos

I am trying to find a way to  create a new account in EOSIO without using CLEOS.
Is there any way to create a new account? Any example for this?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1 - Use EOSJS

2 - Or implement your own, you can start by running cleos with `--print-request` then you will see what sort of calls it makes to create an account.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to do it on the public network there are websites out there where you can create accounts.  it could also be done programmatically but would require access to the private key of the creating account